# Carbon Objects diffInMonths showing 0 when one date is 1st Nov and the other 1st Dec

Tags: php, php-carbon

I have two carbon objects

```php
//$startDate
Carbon\Carbon @1667250000 {#3093 ▼
  date: 2022-11-01 00:00:00.0 Africa/Nairobi (+03:00)
}
```

and

```php
//$endDate
Carbon\Carbon @1669842000 {#2920 ▼
  date: 2022-12-01 00:00:00.0 Africa/Nairobi (+03:00)
}
```

when I run dateDiffInMonths() on them I get 0 but I expect 1

```php
$startDate->diffInMonths($endDate); //0
```

I have tried adding floorMonth() to objects but the answer is still the same.

When I get `$startDate->diff($endDate)` I get the following with days difference as 30

```php
DateInterval {#3102 ▼
  interval: + 30d
  +"y": 0
  +"m": 0
  +"d": 30
  +"h": 0
  +"i": 0
  +"s": 0
  +"f": 0.0
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Rather than a debug output of the two objects, could you include a [mre] of code that creates them, so that we can reproduce the problem ourselves?

Comment: It looks like this might actually be a PHP bug, fixed in PHP 8.1: https://3v4l.org/03NVi Presumably part of the series of bug fixes listed under "Date" here: https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-8.php#8.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are always bugs with DateTime in various PHP versions. These also affect carbon. I've been using this algorithm for years (from https://github.com/jspit-de/dt/blob/master/Dt.php#L1284):

```
function diffInMonth(DateTime $start,DateTime $end): int {
  $endDate = (clone $end)->setTimeZone($start->getTimeZone());
  list($yearStart,$monthStart,$dayStart) = explode(" ",$start->format("Y m dHis"));
  list($yearEnd,$monthEnd, $dayEnd) = explode(" ",$endDate->format("Y m dHis"));
  $mothDiff = ($yearEnd - $yearStart) * 12 + $monthEnd - $monthStart;
  if($dayStart > $dayEnd && $end >= $start) --$mothDiff;
  elseif($dayStart < $dayEnd && $end < $start) ++$mothDiff;
  return $mothDiff;
}

$startDate = new DateTime('2022-11-01 00:00:00.0', new DateTimeZone('Africa/Nairobi'));
$endDate = new DateTime('2022-12-01 00:00:00.0',  new DateTimeZone('Africa/Nairobi'));

$month = diffInMonth($startDate, $endDate);
echo ' Positve: '.$month."\n";  //1

$month = diffInMonth($endDate,$startDate);
echo " Negative: ".$month;  //-1
```

Demo + Test: https://3v4l.org/Tgqcf

This function works the same way with carbon objects.

Comment: This is very good! Actually I think I will replace the algo in Carbon with this.
Just a note: be careful of the timezone:

$first = new DateTime('2022-02-01 01:00 America/Toronto');
$second = new DateTime('2022-01-01 00:00 Europe/Berlin');

Comment: Second note: this require `$start <= $end` else `if($dayStart > $dayEnd) --$mothDiff;` is wrong for negative diff.

Comment: Oh thank you @KyleK. And yes, both dates must be in the same time zone. A correction is still necessary.

Comment: I hope it works like this for negative differences and different time zones now.

Comment: Yep, I took the same path and it passes tests: https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/pull/2697/files#diff-49d63afc8cc6857276354714b91a5a29475b42b3e8b8b12b001da7d7c49433c4R190-R207

Comment: great @KyleK ! And thanks again for the hints. Corrected it for me too.